# Is there a way to check if my cron ran

Tags: centos, cron

I installed a cronjob on my server, now i need to know how to track if the script actually ran? Are there ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may receive mail if your `cron` is configured to do that. Otherwise, you can check in `/var/log/cron.log`.